# button stackView spacing not working -Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistackview

I'm adding a stackView in my viewcontroller in this way:

```
addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.anchor(top: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)
    
    
    let emotionsButton = EmotionButton()
    emotionsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let contentButton = ContentsButton()
    contentButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackView.spacing = 8
    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(emotionsButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentButton)
    
    emotionsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91).isActive = true
    contentButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91).isActive = true
    
    emotionsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 83).isActive = true
    contentButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 83).isActive = true
```

but the result I get is not the desired one; this is what I want:

[image: Stack Desired]

This is what I get:

[image: Stack I get]

Comment: Using a stackview may work, but i suggest you can just create a UIVIew, and put two of your views inside it. And then central horizontally on the "UIView"(the parent view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIStackView` tries to fill the entire width with its contents. So you have some options here

#### Center

Since the stackView's content size is based on its content, you should consider getting rid of the `leading` and `trailing` anchors and use a horizontal center instead. (You can keep one of them alongside with the center one to prevent it from overlapping the edges)

---

#### Dummy views

Another option is to add. dummy views at both sides of the stack view (inside), make them have `clear` color and let them be the last to hug. So. they. can. fill extra space.

---

## Other options

There are other options (like not using the stack view at all) that you can implement to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on a stackview, you shouldnt need to configure the heightAnchor or widthAnchor of your subviews(emotionsButton, contentButton) accordingly.. All you need to configure is the height and width anchor for the **stackView**, and let it resize your subviews accordingly.

```
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
stackView.spacing = 8

stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91 * 2).isActive = true
stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 83).isActive = true

stackView.addArrangedSubview(emotionsButton)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing content hugging priority to `.required` might work.

```swift
stackView.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your arrangedSubViews after your stackview has been added. try setting your spacing after adding the new arrangedSubviews.